# Optimize Performance of Region Checking in List Comprehension

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am modeling a linear process at a number of equally spaced time steps. I have a large list (~70k elements) which corresponds to a location at each time step, `timerange = np.linspace(0, time, iterations, False) * speed`. For each element in this list, I want to compare its value (location) to two other lists and see if that location falls within a valid region. These two other lists, `rot.RegionStarts` and `rot.RegionEnds` (~150 elements) contains the start and end locations, respectively, of each region.
I began tackling this problem with list comprehension, using the following code to achieve the desired result.

```
valid = np.asarray([any((t * dt * speed >= rot.RegionStarts) & (t * dt * speed < rot.RegionEnds) for t in range(iterations)])
```

Upon using this, I realized that execution was rather slow, about 0.4s each time. As make several hundred calls to this line, this greatly slows down the process. I tried using numpy to achieve a similar effect, which required lots of reshaping and repeating.

```
valid = np.any(np.logical_and(
      np.greater_equal(np.repeat(np.reshape(timerange, (-1, 1)), rot.RegionStarts.shape[0], axis=1),
            np.repeat(np.reshape(rot.RegionStarts, (1, -1)), timerange.shape[0], axis=0)),
      np.less(np.repeat(np.reshape(timerange, (-1, 1)), rot.RegionEnds.shape[0], axis=1),
            np.repeat(np.reshape(rot.RegionEnds, (1, -1)), timerange.shape[0], axis=0)),
      axis = 1)
```

Unfortunately, this saw very little performance increase (~0.25s), probably due to the large size of arrays being repeated. Removing lines like `np.repeat` cause problems aligning shape; element-wise `&` could not be executed on 2-d arrays. 
What optimization techiniques can be used speed up this code?

Comment: Are the regions organized in some exploitable fashion/do they overlap? (0-2 in region 1, 2-5 is region 2, etc) Right now you're brute force testing against every region every time. What changes between runs?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Loops over large arrays are not really a good idea in Python. This is why your original list comprehension is not terribly fast.

Your numpy version is loop free, but as far as I know, `np.repeat` actually makes copies of your data, which again, is really inefficient. An alternative would be to use `np.tile`, which maybe does not need to copy the data. But we don't really need to bother since numpy has a great feature called [*broadcasting*](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.05-computation-on-arrays-broadcasting.html), which often makes `np.repeat`/`np.tile` completely unneccessary. Broadcasting basically does `np.repeat/tile` automatically.

To evaluate the performance, I created a more abstract version of your list comprehension:

```
def get_valid_op(arr, lowers, uppers):
    return np.asarray([any((val >= lowers) & (val < uppers)) for val in arr])
```

and also a broadcasting version

```
def get_valid_arr(arr, lowers, uppers):
    valid = np.logical_and(arr.reshape(1, -1) >= lowers.reshape(-1, 1), arr.reshape(1, -1) < uppers.reshape(-1, 1))
    return valid.any(axis=0)
```

The second one is virtually the exact same algorithm as your repeat/reshape code.

With some test data modeled after your description above

```
arr = np.linspace(0, 1000, 70000)
starts = np.linspace(0, 150, 151) * 400
ends = starts + np.random.randint(0, 200, region_starts.shape)  # I assumed non-overlapping regions here
```

we can first `assert all(get_valid_op(arr, starts, ends) == get_valid_arr(arr, starts, ends))` and then time:

```
%timeit -n 10 get_valid_op(arr, starts, ends)
511 ms ± 5.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 get_valid_arr(arr, starts, ends)
37.8 ms ± 3.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

An order of magnitude faster. Not bad to begin with ;-)

Since working with large arrays (`valid` has a shape of `(150, 70000)` before reduction) also has a cost, I then took a step back and returned to loopy-land (just a little bit).

```
def get_valid_loop(arr, lowers, uppers):
    valid = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=bool)
    for start, end in zip(lowers, uppers):
        valid = np.logical_or(valid, np.logical_and(start <= arr, arr < end))
    return valid
```

In contrast to your list comprehension, this version now only iterates over the shorter region limit vectors, which means about two orders of magnitude fewer iterations.

We can then again `assert all(get_valid_op(arr, starts, ends) == get_valid_loop(arr, starts, ends))` and time it:

```
%timeit -n 10 get_valid_loop(arr, starts, ends)
18.1 ms ± 865 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

As the results show, this version is even faster on my "synthetic" benchmark inputs.

In the end you will have to check the versions in your application and see which one performs best.